# Backspace deletes too fast

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

In my android 4.1.2 samsung galaxy s3 mini, when I'm writing sentences, sometimes I want to delete words because grammar mistakes or whatever reason, problem is if I hold backspace after a small time starts to delete at a uncontrollable wild fast pace, and that makes impossible to control and delete messages difficult. It would, for me, be much better a constant speed much slower like windows, letter by letter and not word by word. Is that a serting somewhere?

Comment: That is the functionality  of the  keyboard app. Swiftkey does that but AOSP in my Lollipop doesn't.

Comment: Hey, what you mean by aosp? seems like a organization  not a software, i don''t understand correctly you sentence?

Comment: This "feature" depends on the keyboard. Before we can answer your question, we need to know what keyboard you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by keyboard? I will give answers that probably covers what you are asking. My phone is screentouch, there is not hardware keys they are virtual. I'm using android 4.1.2 and I never made a choice of what keyboard I want software. I have the degault option, and is the same keyboard for wroting in any app or to write an sms.

Comment: Sorry for the grammar mistakes. When on computer I'll correct them.

Comment: The interface (those Q W E R T Y like keys ) using which you write something in your Android is considered a keyboard and it is actually an app in system, so we generally call it a keyboard app, or say soft-keyboard. You've to find an app that doesn't delete words but characters at a time. See if AOSP or Google keyboard app works for you.